# How to Tell if a Thread Pool is Idle in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading, threadpool

I have a thread pool created using

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
```

Is there anyway I can wait till the pool is idle? By which I mean all the threads are not running and nothing is waiting in the queue.

I searched the web and all the solutions don't work for me. For example, I don't want shutdown the pool so `awaitTermination()` wouldn't work. I also know how to `getTaskCount()` but I don't want keep polling the pool, which wastes CPU.

This is a large project and I don't want change all the tasks running in the pool so I am looking for some solution that don't rely on task cooperation. So latches or barriers don't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subclass ThreadPoolExecutor and add hooks with beforeExecute and afterExecute to track task execution however you like, including basic math to count the currently executing tasks. There is also direct access to the Queue with getQueue().

Between these you can easily implement the tracking you ask for. 
I'm curious what your use case is... what will you do with the pool when it is empty?

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there is a way with existing pool implementations. I have a maintenance thread which slows system down so it only does work when thread pool is idle.

Comment: Can't I just use ThreadPoolExecutor's method: getActiveCount().

Comment: I don't think hooking into beforeExecute and afterExecute will always give the right answer. For example there is the possibility of a race if all threads are idle and exactly one job is in the queue. In this case there will be a time instant in the future when a thread in the pool has extracted the job from the queue but has not yet invoked beforeExecute. In that instant the queue is empty and the thread has not yet notified that it is busy, so the thread pool appears idle when actually it isn't. Guess you have to write a custom thread pool implementation if you want to observe its state.

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering if this would work in a real world environment. It involves subclassing `ThreadPoolExecutor` and passing it an `IdleListener`:

```
  @Override
  protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)
  {
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
    listener.working();
  }

  @Override
  protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)
  {
    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    long activeCount = getTaskCount() - getCompletedTaskCount();
    if (activeCount == 1) // yes, one
    {
      listener.idle();
    }
  }
```

The interface:

```
  interface IdleListener
  {
    void working();
    void idle();
  }
```